# .NET web application got spoof-attacked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a .NET web application(MVC2) that's being hosted on my customers' PCs as a server. The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Since a week ago I got some bad news about the software not working properly from some of my customers and after studying the case I found some strange Log in Windows Event Viewer. An Unhandled Exception was thrown witch has some URL in it (The IP address was outside of country) and the strange part was that it was like my application is hosted on that URL. I looked it up and found that the **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host** was that URL not my servers IP address.

Whats that about?! What should I do about it?

Comment: Why don't you reject connections from IP addresses that you don't want them to access your server

Comment: Yeah I've done that already. But I'm curious like hell about this situation and want to know how did they do that? Maybe there's a loop hole in my software architecture or something like that!

Comment: how did you determine "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host"?

Comment: On every request I've checked it out with some hard-coded addresses (localhost, <Local IP address>, <Static IP address>) and threw an exception if it doesn't match. I found it on Event logs of IIS.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the question is. Are you asking how someone could cause that property to be something other than your application's URL? I believe that comes from the HTTP header, so it would be easily spoofed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes that's exactly my question. Beside rejecting that IP range Requests, Is there anything I should do about it? What should I do if someday some requests come from my trusted zone IP range? Do you know any resources about this spoofing method that I can read about? Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's possible because [reverse DNS records](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a45/what-is-reverse-dns-and-do-i-need-it.aspx) are not required for domain names. It looks like someone sets up his domain to your IP address.

At the same time, apparently you have not used [virtual hosting](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a82/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services.aspx), so all HTTP requests (even with wrong Hostname) are handled by your IIS site. You can assign a Host Header Value in Web Site Identification (see the second link for details), to quickly solve the problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Virtual Hosting solved my problem. Although about the rDNS, it may be the problem, but I didn't get a result from running **nslookup <IP>**.